# sed + remove line with word match and only if comment appears in beginning of line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, regular-expression

delete lines with word match is easy

for example when we want to delete the line that match the word - `max.connections`

```
sed '/max.connections/d' /home/conf.txt
```

but how to delete the match lines as following & only line/s that begin with comment as

```
more  /home/conf.txt
#max.connections=438473
#   max.connections=438473
    # max.connections=438473
# max.connections=438473
max.connections=438473
```

note - comment could in the beginning or with space/s

example of expected output

```
more  /home/conf.txt
max.connections=438473
```

Comment: Do you have lines in your file that does _not_ contain the exact string `max.connections`? If not, you could just use `grep '^max\.connections=' file`.

Comment: What I usually use is `awk '!/^#/ && NF' filename`   . This makes sure that the empty lines aren't shown either. Just a hint ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The art is to craft a regular expression that does exactly what you want. In this case, you want to match a line that starts with a `#`, has some characters, and then `max.connection`. In Regular expressions, that would be

```
^                beginning of the line
#                The character '#'
.*               any character, may be repeated 0-infinity times
max.connections  This litteral text
```

or as `sed` command:

```
sed '/^#.*max.connections/d' /home/conf.txt
```

Comment: what in case comment is with spaces from beginning  ( for example couple spaces before the comment )

Comment: Note that this would match `max.connections` if was a substring, e.g. in `# max.connections.in=20000`.

Comment: @they : yes, as would the pattern in the OP's question.

Comment: @yael : `\s` matches a space; so `\s*` matches zero or more spaces. You can put then between the start of line `^` and the `#`.